Websocket connection to java service running on ec2 from aws websocket gateway
I have a java service running on my EC2 instance. This java service is expecting websocket connection. When I try to connect to my service using ec2 public ip address and the path defined in my service it is working fine.
Now I want to implement an aws websocket gateway. But I need to know is there a way that I can connect to my java service (which is expecting websocket connection) from aws websocket gateway. I tried to use lambda to connect to my java service but in that case I have to maintain connections in DB.
Also I cannot use http endpoint as my java service is expecting websocket connection.
Actually main purpose of websocket is to download large documents by sending data in chunks of bytes over websocket connection.
Please help me out in this.
